# .htaccess "No input file specified." error

Tags: apache, .htaccess

first of all this is not related with CodeIgniter (most of the users have this problem CodeIgniter users), Second I tried almost all solutions i could find SO or on the web so far. So here i am ask for your ideas.

My URL for a web CMS Backend Module is like this, and works so far:

> http://www.domain.com.tr/panel/customers.php

When i clicked Add button it should redirect to:

> http://www.domain.com.tr/panel/customers.php/add
>   [And this one shows up with "No input file specified."]

Just to have a clue if you need
`http://www.domain.com.tr/panel/customers.php/` (With slash at the end) opens `http://www.domain.com.tr/`

Additionally my .htaccess file: (I have this .htaccess file in both root folder and in /panel folder)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com\.tr [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www\.domain\.com\.tr\/$1 [R=301,NC]

RewriteRule ^(giris|cikis)/?(.*)$ login.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^sys/bilgilerim/?(.*)$ sys/bilgilerim.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^sys/site-ayarlari/?(.*)$ sys/ayarlar.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^sys/site-istatistikleri/?(.*)$ sys/stats.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^sys/panel-kullanicilari/?(.*)$ sys/pkullanici.php [NC]
```

Additional Info:

> www.domain.com.tr/about-us --- WORKS
>
> www.domain.com.tr/services/blabla --- WORKS
>
> www.domain.com.tr/panel --- WORKS (backend login and dashboard)
>
> www.domain.com.tr/panel/customers.php --- WORKS (Customer management module)
>
> www.domain.com.tr/panel/customers.php/add --- No input file specified. (Customer management module, add customer link)

P.S. This is not a new CMS i used this one(completely my product - handwritten) many times before. So i believe this might because of some server settings which i don't have much permissions to reach it.

I will try everything you suggest and i could try and update this post.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I not found rule in .htaccess for your url
I think file http://www.domain.com.tr/panel/customers.php is exists on your server on disk.

You can add similar rule to .htaccess

`RewriteRule ^/panel/customers.php/(.*) /panel/customers.php?action=$1`

In this case for url http://www.domain.com.tr/panel/customers.php/add in real will opened url http://www.domain.com.tr/panel/customers.php?action=add

Comment: `http://www.domain.com.tr/panel/customers.php/add` should actually open the url `http://www.domain.com.tr/panel/customers.php` the part after this `/add` or `/edit/5` is parsed in php file.

Comment: It will opened. Just try it. Or not use in rule part "?action=$1"

Comment: I'll see if that works because i have 30+ modules and lots of options/actions depending on that.

Comment: You can use one generic rule for all your modules. For example: `RewriteRule ^/panel/([^\.]+)\.php/(.*) /panel/$1.php